# Comaparing two NSArrays to fetch index of particular object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

There are two arrays for serialNo and Student/Teacher

```
serialNo=@[@"123",@"123",,@"453",,@"123",,@"234",,@"123",,@"458"];
Student/Teacher=@[@"S",,@"S",,@"S",,@"T",,@"S",,@"T",@"T",@"S"];
```

Student and Teacher have same serial No. If user wants to check details of Teacher with 123 serial number the index should be 3,

In case of student details, index of serial number should 0.

I tried with different indexes but I haven't yet got the desired output, new changes are making it more complicated for me.

Comment: purticular?  There are two arrays are being...?  @"T",,@"S",,?  making me its more complicate?  You have poor writing skills.

Comment: thanks @El tomato , can you please solve this?

Comment: how would you know teacher object is present at index 3? How would you get Teacher object without knowing it?

Comment: do you do something like array containobject@"T" ?

Comment: check the arrays in question , its an example based on arrays

Comment: as far as i know,it would be easy if you go with dictionaries instead of arrays

Comment: Its best to use a dictionary or a custom object in your case